# Twitter authorized / signed get request returing 401 not authorized

Tags: c#, oauth, httpwebrequest, twitter

I'm trying to make an authorized get request to api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.xml It keeps returning 401 not authorized.  .Ive checked the header and base string against the ones generated in the OAuth tool in twitter developers app page and they are exactly the same.  I've also tried changing the method to post instead of get to no avail.

here is the code:

```
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        HttpWebRequest request =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.xml");
        request.Headers.Add(Uri.EscapeDataString("Authorization: "), authHeader);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

Is there a problem with the way I am sending the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add either the screen_name or user_id of the twitter user you're interested in. For example:  https://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=twitterapi

Comment: duh .. I spent 3 hours pulling my hair out.. Thank you so much.  I had that in the header but forgot to put it in the webrequest url..